# Magento 1.9 : Checkout Validate method repeats calling the code inside

Tags: magento

I have created a module for custom payment and need to call web service to check the inserted mobile number in the checkout then send OTP number to the customer if it is correct. I add the code inside the validate method in the model folder but it sent the SMS 3 times :

```
public function validate()
{

    parent::validate();
    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

    $GUID = sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));



    $phone = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPhoneNO();
    $client = new SoapClient("http://Qitaf/Qitaf_Service.asmx?WSDL");
    $params = array('Requestid' => $GUID , 'StoreCode' => "873", 'Mobileno' => $phone);
    $result = $client->__soapCall('Qitaf_Request_Ecom', array($params));
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $name = $store->getName();


    if ($result->Qitaf_Request_EComResult == "Success|0")
    {
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: so validate() method called 3 times, maybe in loop somewhere

Comment: no loops there .

Comment: can you prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your are working on a Magento 1 one page checkout. Note that Magento validates the data in the checkout after any change in billing/shipping address, shipping method and payment method. So if you fill all this fields, the native validation will be 3 times executed.

Keep in mind that the Magento validation checks the data inserted. I don't understand very well how this payment methods works, but the validation should be separated.

Best regards.